# Does a Kernel Driver compiled for Ubuntu 18.0.4 require any porting issue for running on BTRFS or other modern self-healing file system?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel, filesystem, btrfs

I am trying to estimate the risks for moving to the BTRFS (or any other modern self-healing file system). Does a Kernel Driver compiled for Ubuntu 18.0.4 require any porting issue for running on BTRFS or other modern self-healing file system ?

Comment: There is no `18.0.4` Ubuntu release. Ubuntu releases are year-month, so it is 18.04. What you mean by a "Kernel Driver compiled for Ubuntu 18.0.4"? What kernel driver you mean? Ubuntu kernel supports btrfs, I am using it. And what is "modern self-healing file system"? And what is "porting issue"? Please [edit] your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi , thanks for reply. My question is more general. I am managing several BSP packages for our customers, while most of them have character kernel drivers. So I am trying to estimate the time and complexity risks for involving in the present BSPs the BTRFS Kernel Drivers APIs. What is the "price" of replacing the regular <read><write> FOPs with the BTRFS API's? Hope I am clear

Comment: Not clear at all. What are " BSP packages", "character kernel drivers"?

Comment: Is the question about using btrfs on Ubuntu, or what? There are no"kernel btrfs drivers for Ubuntu". Linux kernel has in-tree btrfs support.

Comment: Ok, the question is about using btrfs in kernel space under Ubuntu 18.04 and later

Comment: So what is the question? It doesn't require any "porting issue". You can create btrfs file systems and use them.

Comment: Great! Got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: The OS API is the same as for any other file systems.

Comment: You can easily convert ext4 to btrfs.